# can some one tell me what the correct syntax of the ruby posts GET is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I am trying to write a rails app and it keeps bombing on this one line of code in my controller.rb file:

```
posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#show
```

Can some one help me?

I am running ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
with rails 3.2.13

**UPDATE**

I took out the line of code above and now I can't get rails to post the value (tag) of the selected check box. Can I get some guidance?

Here is my posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:check_box, :label))
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end

    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end 

private
    def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:check_box, :label)
    end

end
```

Here is my new.html.erb file:

```
<h1>SWORD Mock Device Page</h1>

<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <h2>Android Phones</h2>
        <%= f.check_box(:razr_max1) %>
        <%= f.label(:razr_max1, "Droid Razr Max #1") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.check_box(:galaxyS2) %>
        <%= f.label(:galaxyS2, "Samsung Galaxy S2") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h2>Android Tablets</h2>
        <%= f.check_box(:asusprime3) %>
        <%= f.label(:asusprime3, "Asus Transormer Prime #3") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.check_box(:motoxoom1) %>
        <%= f.label(:motoxoom1, "Motorola Xoom #1") %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%=f.submit "Select" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

here is my routes.rb:

```
SWORDMockDev::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts
  root to: "landing#index"

end
```

and my show.html.erb:

```
<p>
  <strong>Device:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

ironmantis7x

Comment: You have that line of code in your controller? It is not code. It is output result from routes.

Comment: Where do you have this line on your controller? And please post the error

Comment: i need to update the issue based on the input from lulalala and Vimsha. One sec ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:check_box, :label))
  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end
```

You can do:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end
```

The label is not going to submit in the post, only the value of the checkbox
I recommend you to use pry https://github.com/pry/pry and in the controller in the create you can do:

```
def create
  binding.pry
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end
```

And you can see what comes in the params, and what's going on. Also checkout your routes and see if everything is ok with:

```
rake routes
```

Comment: thanks for this. I installed pry and I changed my controller file to look the example above with pry and I get a "undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x007f85d2552508>" error.  Can you help me with this one? Do I need to declare or point to the gem in the controller??

Comment: I recommend you this video for more info about pry
http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails